# How to save and run a Java file in PuTTY?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, putty

*I m a complete newbie on AWS(Amazon Web Services) so this might be a basic question.*

I created an EC2 instance on AWS. I have a windows machine so I'm using PUTTY to connect with the Linux instance.

After getting connected with my EC2 instance, I used the below command to write the Java code,

```
vi java First.java
```

After writing the above code, I got the below screen and I wrote the Java code for a simple "Hello World",

[image]

The problem is now I'm stuck here, what should I do to save what I have written? Where it will be stored, in my laptop or on the EC2? Is there a way through which I can simply upload the file and then just run it from the terminal?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dude did you just try vi first.java.. N write the program n say Esc n then  :  n then wq .. After that compile the program using javac first.java.. N then run it

Comment: @DeepakKumar Thanks for the input, but can you please write this in the answer section with some explanation, I will very much appreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using putty since almost 2 years..

U should open the vi editor using "vi filename.java"

Type the program and then say "Esc : wq" ignore the spaces.. And Esc is the Esc button on keyboard..

Then compile your program using "javac filename.java"

N then run using java filename.java

Comment: Thanks a lot man, it worked. Do you know how to store this file for later use in my AWS?

Comment: I have never dealt with AWS.. But could you please tell me what you get when you execute "pwd" command when you login in putty

Comment: I'm getting /home/ec2-user

Answer (score 2):

See Saumil..

When you login then the directory in which you are landed is your users home directory.. Like in your case "ec2-user"..

So if you do "vi filename" without changing directory then the file is created in the users home directory "/home/ec2-user" .. N that is represented by ~.. Which represents the current users home directory..

N then if you logout and login again then the file stays there.. Nothing happens to that file as long as you manually delete it..

N by the above snapshot I can see that after login you are changing your user to root.. But if you could see after doing sudo you still remain in the same directory. N "~" changes to "ec2-user" because the root users home directory is different..

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using an EC2 instance, so if I terminate that instance then all the files associated with that instance are also deleted. But I got the basic idea about how the files are stored. Thanks

Comment: N thanks for accepting the answer n giving up vote.. :)

Comment: Please merge your two responses into one. You should not post two responses to one question, unless they show two different and competing approaches to the problem. What is not this case.